# Given a 1D ndarray and an integer, what's the most efficient way to generate this ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given `array` and `n` generate `x`

Input

`array = [1 8 38 17]`
`n = 2`

`x = [1 2 3 8 9 10 38 39 40 17 18 19]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code given by Patol75 is quick if the array and n are both small (although it does have to changed to work for any value of n).

```
def f(array,n):
    return sum([[x + i for i in range(n+1)] for x in array],[])
```

It is slow when the array and n are both large. In that case, this is my best shot.

```
def g(array,n):
    temp = np.vstack([array+i for i in range(n+1)])
    return np.hstack([temp[:,i] for i in range(len(array))])
```

Here are the timings.

For small size.

```
array = np.array([1, 8, 38, 17])
n = 2

%timeit f(array,n)
9.44 µs ± 547 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit g(array,n)
23.4 µs ± 1.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

For bigger size.

```
array = np.random.randint(0,1000,1000)
n = 100

%timeit f(array,n)
479 ms ± 46.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit g(array,n)
2.69 ms ± 62.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1, 8, 38, 17]
n = 2
sum([[x, x + n - 1, x + n] for x in array], [])
# [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 38, 39, 40, 17, 18, 19]
```